# What does "capped over" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> 1. He has been **capped over** 100 times and is his country's third-highest goalscorer of all time.
> 2. Bottles of lambic are corked like wine and champagne, but some will have bottle caps that have been **capped over** corks.
> 3. Benefits and costs are **capped over** a 60-year period; fans of the high-speed rail link point out that Britons are still zipping along on railways built 170 years ago.

I can't find the meaning of this phrasal verb anywhere in the internet.

Comment: He has been capped//over 100 times.

Answer (score 2):

"Capped over" isn't really a phrasal verb, at least in the three examples you list here. The verb in these sentences is "capped". "Over" is just a preposition that happens to follow the word "capped" in the examples you give.

The meanings of "cap" for your sentences are, respectively, definitions 2, 5, and 1 in the [MacMillan online dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cap_2?q=capped#cap_2__1).

Answer (score 1):

1) to cap:

to be awarded a cap. In BrE, given award of a cap in football (soccer).

"As an example, the England men's association football teams still awards physical caps. Players are awarded one cap for every match they play — unless they play in a World Cup or European Championship finals tournament."

over 100 times=more than 100 times

[enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_(sport))

2) bottles have corks, and some, like champagne have caps on top of the cork.
We say that bottles are capped =they have caps.

3) to cap something in economics and business: to set a limit on something.

If benefits and costs are capped (the image is a bottle), it means no more money will be spent on something.